# When using oauth to ask permission for Facebook app, does not take in consideration what's in scope

Tags: facebook, oauth

So basically I need my app to allow different permission so I can test it.

But when using the link

"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MYID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&scope=user_friends, publish_actions,friends_birthday"

It only asks for public information access and not the rest.

I have tried many different ways with the link, I can manage it to ask for the email if I put it first after scope, but the rest it does not request it.

I would very much appreciate your help.

My application works with a .sh script in Ubuntu, and needs the permission to run the script on my Facebook account.

I don't require the app to be used by anyone else in the future, this is why I limited myself to asking permission with this kind of link instead of doing some interface.

I don't require the app to be used by anyone else in the future, this is why I limited myself to asking permission with this kind of link instead of doing some interface.

This is the script I would like to run via the APP, so I have to allow application to access permissions accordingly. I don't know if the script work yet:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +"%m/%d")

#Enter your access token below within quotations
ACCESS_TOKEN="TOKEN"

#Get the names and UIDs of your unfortunate friends born on a day like today
curl "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN&query=SELECT%20first_name,uid%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20in%20(SELECT%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1=MYUSERID)AND%20substr(birthday_date,0,5)%20==%20'$NOW'" > birthdaywishtemp.xml

names=`sed -n -e 's/.*<first_name>\(.*\)<\/first_name>.*/\1/p' birthdaywishtemp.xml`
ids=`sed -n -e 's/.*<uid>\(.*\)<\/uid>.*/\1/p' birthdaywishtemp.xml`

F_ARRAY=( `echo ${names}` )
U_ARRAY=( `echo ${ids}` )

#Wish each of them with the same old boring message
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#U_ARRAY[@]} ; i++ ))
do
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/${U_ARRAY[$i]}'
curl -F 'access_token='$ACCESS_TOKEN'' \
    -F 'message=Hey, Happy Birthday...'${F_ARRAY[$i]} \
    https://graph.facebook.com/${U_ARRAY[$i]}/feed >> birthdaywishbackup.log

#Let you know the progress
echo "Wished ${F_ARRAY[$i]}" >> birthdaywishbackup.log
done
```

Comment: It's recommended to post the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: You mean the .sh code or the different links I tried ?

Comment: Edited with the information I think you wanted. I hope you can help me please. Thanks.